# Formula returns -0 instead of INF in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++ and am trying to figure out one thing: I am given this formula to count **z** with different values for **m** given. All good with most of the values except when m=0. I was expecting to receive INF for z, due to the division by 0 in this part **2 / sqrt(m)** but received z= **-0** instead. Is there any formal explanation to this? Because if we take z2  = **2 / sqrt(m)** separately, it will result in inf. I need to write a report and have no idea on how to explain this, found nothing in C++ documentation. Using Microsoft Visual Studio Code 2017 if it matters. Would appreciate your help!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 
#include <math.h>
#include <ctgmath>

int main() {

    float m;
    cout << " Enter the 'm' value: ";
    cin >> m;
    float z;
    float z2;

    z = sqrt(pow((3 * m + 2), 2) - 24 * m) / (3 * sqrt(m) - 2 / sqrt(m));
    z2 = 2 / sqrt(m);
    cout << " \n When 'm' is " << m << ", 'z' value is: " << z << "; 'z2' value is: " << z2 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output in console:

Enter the 'm' value: 0

When 'm' is 0, 'z1' value is: -0; 'z2' value is: -0

tried to use double type instead of float, didn't help :(

Comment: Why do you think `z` should be infinity if `2 / sqrt(m)` is infinity? Have you written out that formula on paper to see how the infinity from `2 / sqrt(m)` is used in it?

Comment: Unrelated, but there's almost never a need to use `float` instead of `double`. All your calculations will be promoted to `double` anyway.

Comment: And please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, fixed the image part, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Just because one part of the expression is infinity, does not mean the entire result is infinity.

It is true that `2/sqrt(m)` would equal `Inf`, but you are *dividing* by it.  The final expression for `z` is `2/(-Inf)` and that does indeed equal `-0`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, this makes sense indeed